# Could not bundle install because of 'pg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

I'm learning R o R. Then, I want to make a website by using postgresql.
But, this error makes me crazy.
Please, help me !

```
$ sudo bundle install

creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_connection.c
pg_connection.c:2323:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gettimeofday' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                gettimeofday(&currtime, NULL);
                ^
1 warning generated.
compiling pg_errors.c
compiling pg_result.c
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: file not found: dynamic_lookup
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

## I tried all ways I could.

For example, I tried to change pass of pg.
But, I couldn't.

Then, I tried

```
$ brew update
$ brew uninstall postgresql
$ brew install postgresql
$ gem install pg
$ bundle install
```

But, it didn't work.

How can I do for this error !?

Comment: You should look into using something like `rvm` or `rbenv`. You won't need to worry about using `sudo` to install anything.

Comment: The OP *is* using RBEnv, just not correctly. *Never* use `sudo` with a RBEnv or RVM hosted Ruby.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? It silently died? It gave you an error output but you didn't understand it? We need more information about what it was output.

Comment: I mean the same error appeared.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can find or install dynamic_lookup and what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

You might require `libpq-dev`, which is the library that always gets me when trying to install the pg gem on a new machine.

Comment: Error: No available formula for libpq-dev 
Searching taps...
Yamaguchi-no-MacBook-Pro:IPnexus Sean$ My Os is mac.

Comment: @shion is it still not working for you? I had a very similar problem, finally after completely rebooting and re-trying brew update, etc, above, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I struck the same problem when running the pg gem 0.17 with Ruby 2.2.1

I just did a `bundle update pg` and it upgraded to 0.18 and it no longer had this compile issue